# yii2, display all translation page titles on the same page

Tags: yii2

Need to make a small mod to a yii2 project, as this site is available in multiple languages I want to display all translated page titles. So if im on the english version of a page i also want to get all of the translated titles of that page.

When I use

```
foreach (\Yii::$app->params['languageUrls'] as $code => $url) {
   echo $url;
}
```

It only displays the current url.

Comment: It would be nice to see what it was that you tried in order to have resolved this yourself, which would have shown us that you did research this before posting the question. When you try, you also learn. If someone just gives you an answer/solution, it would have all been for nothing and I say this for the/your future. You can then edit your post to contain something that may have failed; even that shows an effort on your part. Remember, we're always glad to help :-)

Comment: well I have not tried something because I dont have any knowledge of yii2, and I could not find any documentation or examples about this, thats why I asked this.

Comment: If you don't have any knowledge of Yii2, there's [incredible good guide to Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html) - where you should start - with [an awesome topic about internationalization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the texts that are translated via  `Yii::t()`:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-baseyii.html#t()-detail

Following the example it would be:

```
$username = 'Alexander';
echo \Yii::t('app', 'Hello, {username}!', ['username' => $username], $language);
```

It is not clear from your question how the language and translation is organised in your Yii2 application. Possibly you have ActiveRecord models that contain language fields that are related to the main ActiveRecord models via a Has-Many relationship. In this case, you could refer to the main Model to find the appropriate functions. This however, is not in the Yii2 documentation or guide.